# gunicorn not working under supervisord (but working by itself)

Tags: python, linux, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

i was running gunicorn under supervisor with no problems and this weekend it stopped working.

When do `application start` inside supervisorctl this is in the application log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 9, in <module>
   load_entry_point('gunicorn==19.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
   WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 166, in run
   super(Application, self).run()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 71, in run
   Arbiter(self).run()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 192, in run
   self.halt()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 292, in halt
   self.stop()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 343, in stop
   time.sleep(0.1)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in handle_chld
   self.reap_workers()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
   raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

I'm running application with this configuration:

```
[program:application]
command=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn application:application -c /home/azureuser/rz-app/gunicorn.conf.py
directory=/home/azureuser/rz-app/
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=True
stdout_logfile = /home/azureuser/rz-app/rz-app_log.log
stderr_logfile = /home/azureuser/rz-app/rz-app_errors.log
```

the contents of the gunicorn.conf.py are the following:

```
import multiprocessing

bind = "0.0.0.0:5000"

workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 4 + 1
user = 'root'
group = 'root'

max_requests = 200
max_requests_jitter = 20
```

if i run the command on the terminal outside of supervisor: `gunicorn application:application -c gunicorn.conf.py` things work as expected.

This is a flask application and here is the `application.py` file:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(12)

from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix

from app import application
application.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(application.wsgi_app)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=False)
```

How can i fix this?

EDIT: I have noticed that it seems to be a problem with the root user, when outside supervisor, i ran:

`sudo /usr/local/bin/gunicorn application:application -c /home/azureuser/rz-app/gunicorn.conf.py`, everything works, but when i do:

`sudo su` followed by `/usr/local/bin/gunicorn application:application -c /home/azureuser/rz-app/gunicorn.conf.py` it doesn't work

Comment: have noticed that it seems to be a problem with the root user, when outside supervisor, i ran:

`sudo /usr/local/bin/gunicorn application:application -c /home/azureuser/rz-app/gunicorn.conf.py`, everything works, but when i do:

`sudo su` followed by `/usr/local/bin/gunicorn application:application -c /home/azureuser/rz-app/gunicorn.conf.py` it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, it had nothing to do with gunicorn or supervisor, my application had a dependency that was downloaded only in the user, and i noticed when i did `sudo su` before the command, the same problem appeared, so i logged what was happening while being root `/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --log-file=- application:application -c /home/azureuser/rz-app/gunicorn.conf.py`, added `--log-file=-` and found out the error that was plaguing me.